# What is the precise word to cleverly take a way something

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a precise word to express following behavior?

The postman cleverly or secretly steals items in the mail before it reaches the receiver.

So for the part "cleverly/secretly stealing something", is there a precise word for it?

Thanks, Ahmed

Comment: Why doesn't [**steal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steal) work for you?

Comment: A good 50-cent word for this context is ***purloin***. In some contexts, ***abstract*** might be even better for implying "cleverly/secretly", but it won't work very well in many contexts. ***Pilfering*** is good for "less serious" thefts, and (slangy) ***snaffling*** is even better if you want to be at least *slightly* facetious. The choice depends to some extent on *exactly what nuances* are wanted.

Comment: *Swindle* contextually means to fool someone out of something.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [pilfer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilfer), a synonym of steal with a slightly different connotation:

> especially: to steal stealthily in small amounts and often again and again

It seems like a good fit because you’re describing someone who keeps on stealing from the mail, and is trying to be sneaky about it.

Here’s an example in use:

> [Feds: Postal Service Employee Fesses Up to Pilfering Mail](https://www.insidernj.com/feds-postal-service-employee-fesses-pilfering-mail/)

Comment: Having put this one up myself in a comment, I can't really deny you an upvote! But (perhaps because some of my family have worked for UK Royal Mail) I think of "mail theft by mail workers" as ***far more serious*** than the monetary value of the thefts might imply (it's an *extreme* betrayal of trust, to me). And for me at least, ***pilfer*** always implies "**minor / trivial** theft" (helping yourself to office stationery products for personal use, say).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

> Smuggle

> Sneak

> Pirate (too dramatic in this case)

You can find more of those in this [link](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/take_secretly.html).